# Why we need a topological space to define unordered unlabled configurations of a fixed number of points?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

In every definition of 'configuration space' I read this

> In mathematics, the term “configuration space” **of a topological spac**e X typically refers by default to the topological space

> the configuration space of $n∈N$ point particles that roam around in some **manifold** $X$

> Let X be a closed smooth manifold

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/configuration+space+of+points#unordered_unlabeled_points

For example, why we can't talk about of a 'configuration space' referring to an algebraic variety, instead of a topological space, and instead of 'points' we are not talking about [generic points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_point)?

Why don't we replace the word 'point' of a topological space with the word 'element' of a set?

My idea is that a point is an element, but not every element must be a 'point' with respect to some position, otherwise we end up 'vectorising' the concept of Set, which I do not want, and therefore with the risk of seeing 'the configuration space' as a physical space represented by generalized coordinates and therefore not even using coordinates to 'describe' the phase space.

If we replace the idea of 'point' with that of 'element' it is not necessary to think of the configuration space as a space of possible states and therefore it is not necessary to introduce a coordinate system.

So if we write the definition of 'configuration space' of a topological space **what are we really saying**?

That the elements of the set exist as coordinates and points, but I don't want this because it refers to the idea that the configuration is a 'combination' or permutation of coordinates.
I want to say "there are elements of a set without there being the need to represent or define them as points represented by a coordinate system generalized".

What am I looking for? Is there a category to express "my position"?

Comment: You do not need a topological space, the same notion works in many other categories, e.g. sets, algebraic varieties, complex manifolds,... You just need to make sure that your category is closed under finite direct products, complements, and quotients by free actions of finite groups.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan mm..but why these closures under free actions of finite groups? Where you read this? Why action need to be free and why finite group?

Comment: Well, you take $n$-fold product of your space (variety, scheme, set...), Remove the fat diagonal and divide by the action of the permutation group $S_n$. That's the configuration space in your favorite category.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand why we need to remove fat diagonal. On nLab I read this: The complement $X^{n} \backslash \Delta_{X}^{n}$ of the $n$ -fold Cartesian product by its fat diagonal may be understood as the configuration space of $n$ distinguishable points in $X$. The quotient space of that by the
action of the symmetric group $S_{n}$ nermutation of points in $X$ yields the configuration space of $n$ indistinguishable points in $X$ :
$$
\operatorname{Conf}_{n}(X):=\left(X^{n} \backslash \Delta_{X}^{n}\right) / S_{n}
$$

Comment: You remove the fat diagonal for two reasons: (1) to prevent the collisions between these points in $X$, (2) to make the action of $S_n$ free, so the quotient in the case of a manifold is still a manifold. The quotient when you do not remove the fat diagonal is also useful, it is called $\Sigma^nX$, the symmetric product of $X$.